# Pass global variable value in jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a global variable named errorMessage in my javascript file.
Based on condition i will be setting the value of the error message.
In my jquery validation function i want to access the value of errorMessage based on the condition. Is it possible to do this ?

I am unable to access the errorMessage value while validating... I am getting the blank value. 
when i alert it , its giving correct value.

```
errorMessage = "user exists with '+status+' status";
alert(errorMessage);

$("#form").validate(
{
rules : {
firstName : "required",
lastName : "required",
email : {
required : true,
validEmail : true,
emailExist : true,
}, 
}, 
messages : {
firstName : "Required",
lastName : "Required",
email : {
required : "Required",
validEmail: "Not proper email format",
emailExist : errorMessage, -- not working
},
});
```

Comment: If you want a bunch of error messages in one variable, I believe you'd need an array.

Comment: based on condition, i always get one message

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. If you are asking if you can use the errorMessage variable inside the validate function... yes you can.

Comment: I'm not sure what `status` is unless we see how it's initialized, but try comparing with `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: Put your if-statement within a function and return the correct message. I assume you know where "status" comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Before sending error message, you are checking database for user status. So, from back end return some flag for error type. For example, 0 and 1. Then use a function with if-else statement for selecting right error text. For other alternatives read http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/